# Can not access Jupyter server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, jupyter-notebook

I have created a `Jupyter Notebook` server on `Raspberry Pi` using `ssh` on an `iPad` using `jupyter notebook --allow-root --no-browser`.

Jupyter sent a message similar to `The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=77....`.

But when I try to access Jupyter using a browser (`Safari` on iPad or `Chrome` on Mac) I couldn't access it. I pinged `127.0.0.1` with success but I don´t know if this means anything useful for my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address. That means that it refers to "the current machine". When you are on your Mac and you attempt to access `http://127.0.0.1:8888`, your browser is attempting to connect *to the Mac*, not to the Raspberry Pi.

To access the notebook server on your Pi, you have a couple options:

1. You can configure the notebook as described in the section "[Running a public notebook server](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#running-a-public-notebook-server)" in the Jupyter documentation.
2. You can use ssh forwarding to forward local port 8888 to port 8888 on your Pi. This should be as simple as logging in to your Pi using `ssh` like this:

   ```
   ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 your.pi.address
   ```

   As long as you are connected to the Pi, you should be able to use the original `http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=77....` URL on your Mac.

The second option is arguably both easier and more secure.